# getarguments in typo3 from URL

Tags: url, parameter-passing, typo3, realurl

I am working in TYPO3 .....

how can i get arguments from URL

i passed arguments in url like this ,

as a template in resources folder , file name : list.html

```
<f:form action="update" object="{hotel}" arguments="{myArgument: argumentname}" name="hotel">
```

and in controller in updateAction() , i want to fetch that agruments , so i write like this ,

```
$this->view->assign('hotel', array('test' => 'hello' . isset($this->arguments['myArgument']) .'@@' . $this->getParametersSafely('myArgument')));
```

and i make the function in controller...

```
public function getParametersSafely ($parameterName) { 
  if ($this-> request-> hasArgument ($parameterName)) {
     return $this-> request->getArgument($parameterName);
 }
}
```

So please help me this is not working

Answer (score 0):

I guess "this is not working" means the string in the fluid variable `{hotel}` is kind of not what you expect? Or what exactly is not working?

First of all `isset()` returns a boolean, that you should not just add to your string.
Secondly, if you use `arguments="{myArgument: argumentname}"`fluid expects argumentname to be a variable passed to the template. If you want to pass a string, you need to specify it: `arguments="{myArgument: 'argumentname'}"`.

Comment: I wrote like this ,

    $temp=$this->request->getArguments();
    $this->view->assign('result','hi : '.$temp);

but this display output as,
    hi : Array

Comment: i want to display the value of argument ('argumentname')